# AzureTable with Powershell : Cannot find an overload for "ExecuteQuery" and the argument count: "1"

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-table-storage

I want to extract the data from Azure Table Storage to a CSV file with PowerShell 7.1.4

Here is my PS script :

```
$StorageAccountName = "" 
$StorageAccountKey = "" 
$table = ""

$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey 

$table = Get-AzureStorageTable –Name $TableName -Context $Ctx

$query = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery" 

$query.FilterString = "(Timestamp ge datetime'2021-12-30T06:00:00Z' and Timestamp lt datetime'2021-12-30T12:00:00Z')"

$data = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery($query)
```

I get the following error :

```
> $data = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery($query)
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find an overload for "ExecuteQuery" and the argument count: "1".
```

Comment: added Aztable as update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot find an overload for “Insert” and the argument count: “1”.
>
> Cannot find an overload for “ExecuteQuery” and the argument count:
> “1”.

The above error occurs when you have both the `Azure.Storage` and `Az.Storage` modules loaded at the same time. There are two different versions of the DLL file `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll`. In some cases, it would use the `Azure` and in other cases it would use the `Az` one. The problem is that the `Azure.Storage` module is required to query or write to a storage table.

As a workaround ,you need to force any query and entity objects to use the same version of the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll` file, as the `Azure.Storage` module. You can do this by saving the version information to a variable, and then specifying it when you create these objects.

You can try with below where we create the `$assemblySN` variable with the assembly’s full name. Then , we add that to the `New-Object` command for creating the query object from the `TableQuery` class. :

```
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $TableName -Context $Ctx
#get the $table Assembly FullName
$assemblySN = $table.CloudTable.GetType().Assembly.FullName
#Create a table query.
$query = New-Object -TypeName  "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery,$assemblySN"
$query.FilterString = "(Timestamp ge datetime'2021-12-30T06:00:00Z' and Timestamp lt datetime'2021-12-30T12:00:00Z')"
$entities = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery($query)
```

For more information you can refer the ***[`blog`](https://www.catapultsystems.com/blogs/azure-storage-powershell-error-cannot-find-an-overload/)*** by **Matthew Dowst**.

**Update:**

If the Issue still occurs then you can use ***[`Aztable module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell)*** like :

```
$cloudTable = (Get-AzStorageTable –Name $table -Context $Ctx).CloudTable 
$data = Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable -customFilter "PartitionKey eq '$filedate'"
```

Comment: Thanks, when I used this code, it gives: $query = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery, … Cannot find type [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery,System.Private.CoreLib, | Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Comment: > Get-Module : Az.Accounts (2.7.0) | Az.Storage (4.1.0)

Comment: @admin, please run this command first : `Install-Module -Name Azure.Storage` and then use the code . let me know if you get any other error

Comment: already executed this command, the same error is displayed.
When I run get-module it just gives Az.Storage 2.7.0 but not Azure.Storage, normal ?
Import-Module -Name Azure.Storage ==> Assembly with same name is already loaded

Comment: @admin, if the above is not working then can you try using Aztable module . you can refer this Microsoft documention : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell

Comment: Yes, using AzTable module, works fine, thank you.

$cloudTable = (Get-AzStorageTable –Name $table -Context $Ctx).CloudTable 

$data = Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable -customFilter "PartitionKey eq '$filedate'"